# Noir css can't load?

Tags: clojure, noir

I figure out I can not load css in noir apps.
Neither can not change the css soure file, is there anything wrong with the route?

```
(ns my-web.views.common
  (:use noir.core
        hiccup.core
        hiccup.page-helpers
        ))

(defpartial layout [& content]
            (html5
              [:head
               [:title "website from noir"]
               (include-css "/css/reset.css")]
              [:body
               [:div#idnumber content]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you keeping the css? This would assume that the css is located in `/resources/public/css/reset.css`.

If you're familiar with Rails and the asset pipeline, you should take a look at Dieter (https://github.com/edgecase/dieter).

Comment: I am sorry that I don't familiar with that,I keep css in that dir.And It doesn't work anyway.I can not change that file, or I change the file, it just doesn't work, and nothing happens in my chrome, but the font,and font size.